# Code Igniter URL appending

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

This is my first question, I am new at CodeIgniter and trying to run a login code at XAMPP server. I have two views.

myform.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="/form/myform" title="Create an Account">


<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"  size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"  size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

formsuccess.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your form was successfully submitted!</h3>

<p><?php echo anchor('form', 'Try it again!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

and a controller:

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));

                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
                        array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
                );

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {

                        $this->load->view('myform');
                }
                else
                {
                        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
                }
        }
}
```

Now when I run this on my localhost `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/form/`

it opens myform view but when I click on the submit button the URL becomes `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/form/localhost/codeigniter/index.php/form/`. It means it appends the url. It's a long question just to clarify you people. Please help.

Comment: Just check you have set your base url and not left it blank because in codeigniter 3 versions not recommend now. Also in your password value you have your set_value('username') and not set_value('password')

Comment: What might be better for you is the form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Comment: yes i have set my base url as localhost.. i have extracted code igniter in htdocs, please give some example code and its path settings, thats run perfectly. i would get the idea then.

Answer (score 2):

If you set your base url, just change :

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="/form/myform" title="Create an Account">
```

to

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>form/myform" title="Create an Account">
```

Comment: if you can upload sample code with proper path settings, i would be thankful for this regard.

Comment: @JunaidAli The problem is you are going for `form/myform` and in your Form controller the name of the function is `index` and not `myform` so change action to `form/index` or change name of function

Comment: it just continues to append the url.. i am frustrated of this.. i am new to this.. cant figure it out. please give me a code and config settings if you can bro.

Comment: @JunaidAli did you set base url in config?

Comment: yes i have set it to localhost as i have extracted my code igniter in htdocs

Comment: @JunaidAli Why don't you try and use `https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html` it is very easy and that should work 100%, for form open you would do just `echo form_open('form/myform');`  and for inputs check url

Comment: done! thank you marko.. can i have your skype contact, it would be easier for me to ask you in need as i found you quiet helpful.